Is it possible to find r in terms of the other variables?
I've never posted before and I'm sorry if this kind of question isn't suited to this forum.
In the image I've attached, I'm wondering if it's possible to find the length r in terms of the lengths a and b, and angles α and β.
This is for a 3D scanner I'm building.

Thank you!

More a question for math.stackexchange I’m afraid - I think best practice would also be to include the picture in the question rather than a link to it.

@Nethesis as a new user, the OP is, I believe, not able to inline images.

New user: yes, unfortunately it's off-topic here. But a cool problem to think about as part of your project! I can migrate this to math.stackexchange, but you might want to edit the question to add some more context about what sort of maths you are familiar with and what you might have already tried.

This is not metric-geometry. Please, choose the tags carefully. Read its descriptions.

Thanks so much for the help everyone.

We have that, if we let the base length be $h$:
$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{h}{r+a}, \cos(\beta) = \frac{h}{r+b}$
Thus, we have that $$\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)} = \frac{\frac{1}{r+a}}{\frac{1}{r+b}} = \frac{r+b}{r+a}$$
Multiplying and rearranging yields
$$r+b = \frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)}(r+a)$$
Meaning $$r = \frac{\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)}a-b}{1-\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)}} = \frac{a\cos(\alpha)-b\cos(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)}$$

Very elegant, thank you!
